# Show more ads, but without a top banner

Tags: feature-request

I actually like to get programming related ads. Hence I would want to activate this option:

[image]

My problem with that is that the top banner is too obtrusive. Can't we get a third option which shows more ads, but just in the side panel?

Bonus feature: Just ads for other things than the stack exchange network. (Having that ad privilege kind of suggest that the user know a lot about SE)

Comment: As a workaround for now, you could have an adblocker whitelist SO, but specifically block that top div

Comment: There are no more ads to show. The reduce ads privilege hides the two banner ads that would otherwise be displayed. The *only* thing that preference does is re-enable those banner ads.

Comment: The problem with that bonus feature is that it would also hide Area 51 ads where they're trying to get enough folks on board to start a Beta site. I don't think they'll be happy with the idea of their potential target audience being able to preemptively block those ads. On the other hand SO doesn't care about folks using ad blockers so maybe that won't be a big deal.

Comment: @animuson - I think the word "more" ended up in the new option just because it's in the old one. It doesn't sound like from the request the OP actually wants more ads than usual. Maybe "Show me all advertisements" would be better wording. Or "Reduce ads" and "Do not reduce ads".

Comment: @BSMP but with just the "Off" option, the area 51 users would still not be able to display the ads. So is there really a loss?

Comment: @animuson The "more" was from the `Do not show me *more* advertisements` option. I want more (as per defined in that option), but have them in the right panel.

Comment: The question here is, does this option affect ads on the right column or not?